# Customizing spree e-commerce view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, view, spree, deface

I am while customizing my spree e-commerce application. At first I added the `spree_bootstrap_frontend` gem  and I want to customize the oredres/edit view as follow:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path =>"spree/orders/edit",
                     :name => "continue_shopping",
                     :replace => "erb[loud]:contains('link_to t(:continue_shopping), products_path')",
                     :erb => "<%= link_to t(:continue_shopping), products_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>")
```

but there's no change.
Could you please help my first customization view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just use `:text` key instead of `:erb`:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path =>"spree/orders/edit",
                     :name => "continue_shopping",
                     :replace => "erb[loud]:contains('link_to Spree.t(:continue_shopping), products_path')",
                     :text => "<%= link_to t(:continue_shopping), products_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>")
```

Comment: which versions of `spree` and `spree_bootstrap_frontend` are you using?

Comment: I am using using spree '2.4.3' and gem 'spree_bootstrap_frontend', github: '200Creative/spree_bootstrap_frontend', branch: 'master'

Comment: As you can see here:

https://github.com/200Creative/spree_bootstrap_frontend/blob/490c13e5669edab6f1631ef74b59f975a1b523f5/spree_bootstrap/frontend/app/views/spree/orders/edit.html.erb#L9

the erb you are trying to find in the page is different from the one present in the extension. I think it's just matter to update the `t` method with the `Spree` namespace. Going to update the answer :)

Comment: yes that's true! I change the 't' method by 'Spree.t' method and it works thank you :)